# Animate the camera depending on the event

Tags: aframe

With a simple code it is possible to move the position of the camera when clicking on an object. But is it possible to animated the camera to move to those positions?

This is my code:

```
    <a-scene>
        <a-entity >

            <a-box id="box01" color="#6173F4" position="1 0 0"></a-box>
            <a-box id="box02" color="#6173F4" position="-1 0 0"></a-box>
            <a-camera id="cam">
                <a-cursor></a-cursor>
            </a-camera>
            <script> 
            var cam = document.querySelector('#cam');
            var caja1 = document.querySelector('#box01');
            var caja2 = document.querySelector('#box02');

            caja1.addEventListener('click', function () {
                cam.setAttribute('position' , {x: 1, y: 0, z: 4});
                cam.setAttribute('rotation' , {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0});
            }); 
            caja2.addEventListener('click', function () {
                cam.setAttribute('position' , {x: -3, y: 3, z: 4});
                cam.setAttribute('rotation' , {x: -30, y: -30, z: 0});
            }); 
            </script>
        </a-entity>
    <a-text value="Hello, A-Frame!" color="#FFF"
    position="0 0 1" scale="1.5 1.5 1.5"></a-text>
    <a-sky color="#4069b4"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don McCurdy has got you covered.
Check his demo out, which might be exactly what you want:
https://sandbox.donmccurdy.com/checkpoints/
(fixed broken link)

Comment: Thanks!! dirkk0. That's what i was looking for.

Comment: Link is broken (again)

Comment: The demo isn't running anymore, but here's the code:
https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/examples/checkpoints